# Django - DetailView with FormMixin and initial

Tags: django

I have DetaiView for my post and I want to use a form in this view so I decided to use `DetailView` with `FormMixin`. I need to set some initial to this form and I don't know how to do it. Here is my code:

`models.py`

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField("Nick", max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField("Body")
    created = models.DateTimeField("created", auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField("Updated", auto_now=True)
```

`forms.py`

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = (
            "name",
            "email",
            "body"
        )
```

`views.py`

```
class PostDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = "newspaper/post-detail.html"

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("post-detail", kwargs={"slug": self.object.slug})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form"] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)


    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

So I want to post in `CommentForm` to post of this `DetailView`. I hope you understand :D.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `FormMixin` you can specify form's initial using [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.initial) attribute:

```
class PostDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = "newspaper/post-detail.html"
    initial={'name': 'John'}
```

Or get_initial method:

```
def get_initial(self):
   return {"post": self.get_object() }
```

Comment: Yeah but I need to set initial like this `{"post": self.object}`

Comment: @xaos_xv use get_initial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial

Comment: I changed it but now when I want to save my form in `form_valid` I get this error: `NOT NULL constraint failed: newspaper_comment.post_id`

Comment: @xaos_xv try to add `post` to the form's field.